# AWS lambda - não consigo conectar ao banco RDS, apenas localmente

Tags: banco-de-dados, amazon-aws

Estou tentando conectar a uma instância RDS a partir de uma lambda. Eu fiz e testei a lambda localmente, funcionou perfeitamente. Porém, quando fiz o deploy para a AWS o código é executado normalmente até a parte em que é feita a conexão com o banco. A partir disso, nem mesmo as mensagens de log aparecem.

Obs: Estou usando `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;`

Obs2: Não estou usando VPC na lambda.

Obs3: Tenho lambdas mais antigas que funcionam normal, apenas as novas estão com este problema, por mais que as configurações sejam iguais.

Essa é a parte relevante do código:

```
if (body && body.modality_id) {

            console.log('Just debugging...')

            DB.query("call sp_create_transaction (?)",[body.modality_id])
                .then(results => {
                    if (results[0][0]) {
                        if (results[0][0].Error) {
                            helper.body = { 'message': results[0][0].Error };
                            console.log('Error:' + results[0][0].Error);
                        }
                        else {
                            helper.statusCode = 200;
                            helper.body = results[0];
                            console.log(helper.body);
                            console.log('EXECUTION SUCCESS:');
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        helper.statusCode = 401;
                        helper.body = { 'message': 'Falha ao buscar taxas.' };
                        console.log('Error: Rates not found.');
                    }
                    callback(null, helper.response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    helper.statusCode = 500;
                    helper.body = { 'message': 'Por favor, informa ao time de suporte técnico o código DAN-54.' };
                    console.log('Error: DAN-54');
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(null, helper.response);
                });
        }
```

Aqui é a saída do log:

```
START RequestId: fb134979-7d0e-4fa3-b7c8-4192f4765ea8 Version: $LATEST
2019-05-28T23:47:26.609Z fb134979-7d0e-4fa3-b7c8-4192f4765ea8 INFO Just debugging...
END RequestId: fb134979-7d0e-4fa3-b7c8-4192f4765ea8
REPORT RequestId: fb134979-7d0e-4fa3-b7c8-4192f4765ea8 Duration: 1273.33 ms Billed Duration: 1300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 79 MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dificil dizer, mas como a duração da execução parece pequena pra execução da proc, minha hipótese é que a lambda está retornando antes da execução assíncrona de DB.query(), por isso você não vê mais saída. Para confirmar podes aumentar o timeout e se for isso mesmo, usar async/await ou a API de Promises para esperar o resultado antes de invocar o callback de retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Eu implementei alguns lambda conectando no RDS usei o [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) pra isso que é tipo um terraform de lambdas, enfim. Pra poder conectar no RDS seu lamnda tem que ter acesso a VPC, a subnet que o banco se encontra mais permissões no RDS em si

Tem que configurar na parte de network na pagina do proprio lambda

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: salvei a resposta imcompleta sem querer e ja levei um negativo :'(

Comment: Resolvido o problema ;)

Comment: Valeu @JaksonFischer em breve pretendo subir um codigo de exemplo de lambda acessando RDS no meu github, ainda nao tive tempo. Por o link aqui pro pessoal acompanhar a documentação e muito falha entao e de exemplo em exemplo que a gente vai pegando a coisa https://github.com/krismorte

Comment: Opa, isso é sempre bom. Infelizmente aqui tem uma galera que está com o dedo pronto pra negativar, mas dar um voto a favor, necas... Infelizmente sofremos muito com isso, mas não tem o que se fazer :/